# Which package to share editing, in real-time, over http?

Tags: remote, http

I seem to remember a package mentioned once, that you would activate in Emacs, and then other people could follow what happens in almost real time in your Emacs by accessing a URL with a web-browser.

I can't for the life of me find the name of this package.

Comment: I don't know how to describe it better, please edit if you do - it *was* impatient-mode I was looking for.

Comment: (Drew deleted his comment, so my reply - above - seems detached and deranged now.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might be thinking about `impatient-mode`, which is available in MELPA, and also [on GitHub](https://github.com/netguy204/imp.el).  I haven't tried it myself, but according to [Sacha Chua's blog post](http://sachachua.com/blog/2015/02/emacs-peer-peer-coaching-easier-use-impatient-mode-share-buffer/) about it it seems to be easy to use:

> 1. Install the `impatient-mode` package.
> 2. Call `M-x httpd-start`.
> 3. Configure the firewall to allow incoming connections.
> 4. Put the selected buffer into `impatient-mode`.
> 5. Share the link with my IP address (form: `http://my.ip.ad.dress:8080/imp/`)

Comment: Yes it is easy to use and if you have a web service already running on that computer, you can skip the httpd-start step.

Comment: That was the blog post I read, but my search skills failed me miserably - I was even searching for Sacha's blog specifically. I think I found impatient-mode, but the blurb "See the effect of your HTML as you type it." confused me, as that is certainly not what I am looking for. Will try it. Thanks!